# I have problems with installing neo4j.py under Windows

Tags: python, neo4j

During installation I have following error:

```
File "C:\JPYTHONNEO\pom.py", line 56, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(path)
KeyError: 'project.artifactId'
```

if I add two lines of code to pom.py:

```
def __getitem__(self, path):
    element = self.tree.findtext(self.__path(path))
    if element is None:#added  
        element = self.tree.findtext(self.__path('dependencies'))#added 
    if element is None:
        element = self.tree.findtext(self.__path('properties.' + path))
    if element is None and self.parent is not None:
        element = self.parent[path]
    if element is None:
        raise KeyError(path)
    return self.pattern.sub(lambda match:self[match.groupdict()['var']], element)
```

I get following error despite the fact that I ve python 2.7 installed.

```
EnvironmentError: Neo4j.py installation requirements unfulfilled.

 * For Jython, the source installation requires Jython version 2.5.
 * For Jython 2.2 you can still install pre-packaged binary distributions.
   These can be obtained at http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j.py/
 * For Python, the source installation requires Python 2.5.
```